# using Data Modeler (view relational diagram) in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

when trying to view 'Reports > Data Modeler Reports > Design Contents > Relational Model > Relational Designs' in Oracle SQL developer. It gives "Data Modeler reporting repository required." Can anyone see what's wrong with it? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a reporting repository schema like this:

```
SQL> create user DM_REPORT_REPOS identified by DM_REPORT_REPOS;

User created.

SQL> grant connect, resource to DM_REPORT_REPOS;

Grant succeeded.
```

Then in SQL Developer Data Modeller you can open the model you want to report on and export it to this repository via File/Export/To Reporting Schema.  You will need to create a new Connection for the schema you just created.

Then in SQL Developer you can also create a new Connection for the repository and select this to run the reports.

Comment: @Ivanov Sorry, no.  I don't even know how I knew this myself back then!